# How to read save.txt file and set it to label

Tags: python, tkinter, save, pytube

(Im making gui application with tkinter and pytube, it will download your youtube video to your located directory.)
Hello, im on my way to make my own application in python, but it isnt easy. I cannot come up with solution. I want my app to make saves. Everytime i choose a directory, it will write into save.txt file, but when i start the application, I dont know how to load the file to the label, which is showing current directory. Also i want to change the `ytbvideo.download(path)`. Instead of path I want to read my save.txt file. In my saves.txt file is only directory. For example, in the saves.txt is now this `C:/Python/VideoDownloader`, so if the app reads the save.txt, it shouldnt be problem i guess. This is my code, it works fine, so only problem is, i dont know, what to add. **This is my code:**

```
import os
from tkinter import Text, Label, Tk, Entry, StringVar, Button
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk



root= Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')
root.title('Youtube Video Downloader')
root.configure(bg='gray')



Label_1=Label(root,text="Youtube video downloader", font=("bold",20), bg='gray')
Label_1.place(x=150,y=10)

Label_2=Label(root, text="Paste the link here", font=(10), bg='gray')
Label_2.place(x=240, y=75)



mylink=StringVar()

pastelink=Entry(root, width=60, textvariable=mylink)
pastelink.place(x=140, y=100)



def chooseDir():

   
    global path
    path = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Choose a download directory")
    tk.Label(root, text=path, bg='gray').place(x=240,y=300)
    saves()

def downloadVideo():
    videoLink=str(mylink.get())
    ytbvideo=YouTube(videoLink).streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
    ytbvideo.download(path)




def saves():
    saves = open('data.txt', 'w')
    saves.write(path)   



    
def quitApp():
    root.destroy()
    



   

Button(root,text="Download video", width=20, bg='black',fg="white", command=downloadVideo).place(x=240, y=130)
Button(root,text="Choose location", width=20, bg='black',fg="white", command=chooseDir).place(x=240, y=160)
Label_3=Label(root, text="Curent location: ", font=("bold"), bg='gray')
Label_3.place(x=250, y=245)

Label_3=Label(root, text="by yakubiq", font=("bold"), bg='gray')
Label_3.place(x=0, y=375)

Button(root,text="Quit", width=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=quitApp).place(x=445, y=370)






root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to open save.txt in reading mode, as in:

```
 savesReader = open("data.txt", 'r')
```

Then you can use savesReader.read() to read from the "data.txt" file.

Comment: @JohnyPro yeah, but then i cannot edit that file everytime i change the dir

Comment: @JohnyPro can i do it like that? `def saves():
    saves = open('data.txt', 'w')
    saves.write(path)   
    saves = open('data.txt', 'r')
    data = saves.read()`

Comment: oh ok if you want to read and write to the file simultaneously you can use `open("data.txt", 'w+')` instead of `open("data.txt", 'r')`

Comment: @JohnyPro but still, it doesnt work, the dir doesnt show when i start the app                `def chooseDir():

   
    global path
    path = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Choose a download directory")
    tk.Label(root, text=data, bg='gray').place(x=240,y=300)
    saves()

def downloadVideo():
    videoLink=str(mylink.get())
    ytbvideo=YouTube(videoLink).streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
    ytbvideo.download(data)




def saves():
    saves = open('data.txt', 'w+')
    global data
    data = saves.read()`

Comment: @JohnyPro this is the error, when i want to choose the dir, but at start, when it should change the label from none to directory in data.txt, there isnt any error. `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python\VideoDownloader\VideoDownloader.py", line 36, in chooseDir
    tk.Label(root, text=data, bg='gray').place(x=240,y=300)
NameError: name 'data' is not defined`

Comment: @rioV8 i didnt know context manager exists until now

Comment: I think its because you wrote `tk.Label(root, text=data,....` it should be `tk.Label(root, text=path....`

Comment: @KuroDevStuff Then you read the wrong Python books/sites, teaching file stuff without context managers is asking for some possible weird errors in big programs

Comment: @rioV8 bruh, i dont read anything, i started a week ago D:

Comment: @KuroDevStuff You have done this Tk stuff without reading any Tk

Comment: @rioV8 ye, i dont know anything about python. I saw video from Dev Ed, he showed me tk and i wanted to do something like that. I saw post on Instagram, python for beginners. There was a tip, first of all, learn ytb downloader and i did it. I was happy with result and i wanted to finish the project. I showed it to my friends and they were si excited, because im dumb and they didnt trust me i can do that. Someone said to make directory saves and I started.. my only book for programming is making plugins in java for minecraft D: . Everything i did was from my programming experience, stack and ytb

Comment: @KuroDevStuff What holds you back in reading about Python and Tk and start to understand what you copy/paste

Comment: @rioV8 i understand my code, if i dont, i will read books or sites

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

```
var=open('[file directory]', 'r')
myvar= var.readlines()
tklabel=Label(root, text=f"{myvar}", font=(10), bg='gray')
var.close()
```